# Customizable alarm clock/set off a YouTube video on a timer

Tags: youtube

I want to wake up to the sound of a particular YouTube video. Is there a way I can set an alarm-clock/youtube-video-timer on my computer, so that the video will start playing at a predefined time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[www.timer-tab.com](http://www.timer-tab.com) lets you do precisely that.

Look at the bottom, at settings, and paste a YouTube link in the "YouTube alarm" field.

You can use the `t` argument to make Timer Tab play the video at a predefined time. For example, if you enter the following address http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZX3lG306N4&t=10, Timer Tab will play the video at the 10th second.

Also, you can make Timer Tab repeat the YouTube video by appending `&repeat` to the YouTube link, e.g. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZX3lG306N4&t=10&repeat. Which can be handy to make sure you wake up.

**Disclosure:** I wrote this web app.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Windows you can use the Task Scheduler to launch your favorite browser to the URL of the YouTube video. You would set the action to something like:

```
C:\Path\to\browser.exe http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxx
```

Not a web oriented solution but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Alarm Clock Server](http://www.alarmclockserver.com), which is based on YouTube videos. Love to wake up with my favorite song.

Comment: link is currently dead